# В другое Android приложение не передается картинка через интент

Tags: android, android-intent, picasso

Пытаюсь получить картинку с интернета, сохранить ее на телефон и отправить ее сразу через какой либо мессенджер либо почтовик не открывая галерею для выбора картинки.

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String remoteUrlString = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/Extreme_QR_code_to_Wikipedia_mobile_page.png";
    private Button btnStart;
    private Context context;

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER = 14222;

    private File file = null;
    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStart = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                resendImage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void resendImage() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            System.out.println("PERMISSION_GRANTED == WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: true");
            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(remoteUrlString)
                    .into(target);
            sendImg();
        } else {

            System.out.println("PERMISSION_GRANTED == WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: false");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER);
            }
        }
    }

    private Target target = new Target() {

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Extreme_QR_code_to_Wikipedia_mobile_page.jpg");

                        FileOutputStream ostream = null;
                        ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                        ostream.close();
                        galleryAddPic(file);
                        setFile(file);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {
            }
        }
    };

    private void galleryAddPic(File file) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void sendImg() {

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getFile());
        sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER && grantResults.length == 1) {

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                resendImage();

            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.devtolife.myapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="START" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Когда открывается выбор приложений для отправки то картинка отсутствует во вложении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверял галерею - картинка загрузилась и нормально открывается.
Что может быть?

Comment: Вы вызываете `sendImg();` не дождавшись загрузки - в интенте скорее всего отправляется `null`. Интересно, в чём выигрыш от `Picasso` в такой задаче?

Comment: Я пробовал просто получать картинку через URL  без `Picasso` - но отказался, так как с нужного мне сервера получал ошибку 405. Пикасо же отрабатывает нормально -  картинку скачивает.

Comment: Действительно - `null` в `intent`. Как сделать чтобы вызов `sendImg()` происходил после загрузки картинки? В `picasso` нашел `callback()` используемый только при вставке фото в `ImageView`.

Comment: Вызвать там, где Вы делаете `setFile(file);`. С Пикассо код получается запутанный + изображение на выходе не оригинальное, а перекодированное и, соответственно затраты на раскодирование и компрессию.

Comment: Пробовал, на каком бы этапе не вызывал `sendImg()` в любом случае он отрабатывает раньше чем картинка загрузится на телефон - в итоге `null` в `intent`.

Comment: Вот об этом я и говорю - всё запутано. Предайте файл параметром в метод `sendImg(file)` и поставьте его вызов прямо на место вызова `setFile(file)`

Comment: Переделал 'sendImg()' в 'sendImg(file)' - результат тот же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По коду не буду проходится, отвечу так:

Вас здесь из стандарта быстро спасет обертывание вашего Thread с FutureTask, чуть больше кода для AsyncTask, ну а лучше смотрится Rx. Уйдут танцы с Picasso, он здесь явно не для того, и по окончанию записи картинки в файл сможете нормально вызвать вашу fun sendImg(). Для быстрой проверки можете сделать:

```
setFile(file);
sendImg();
```

хоть это и плохо, но startActivity постит вроде всегда на MainThread... так что должно заработать.

Comment: Не совсем понял по  поводу танцев с `picasso`. Я к ней прибегнул лишь из-за того, что, обычным `HttpURLConnection` от сервера получал вместо картинки ошибку 405.

Comment: @V.March, неправильно оформленный запрос - не повод извращаться с дополнительными библиотеками, тем более что Picasso именно для этой задачи не предназначена.

Comment: @woesss Вот от Вас я только что и узнал что мой запрос был неправильным, а до этого я свято верил, что я, все делал правильно, а вот сервер что-то не хочет отдавать картинку - по этой причине начал искать альтернативу. Опыт сильная штука.

Comment: @woesss А как Вы узнали что я неправильно составил запрос?

Comment: @V.March, у меня есть хрустальный шар и когда луна в зените он показывает чужой код))) Любая библиотека - это всего лишь готовое решение того, что можно сделать самому. Если Picasso грузит, а у Вас не получается - значит дело в Вашем коде.

Comment: @woesss Хм, шар конечно хорошо, но надеялся что пример какой то подкинете. Понял что в любом случае очереди придется делать. Буду учить RX с Picasso танцевать.

Comment: @V.March, а что, нигде не найти пример загрузки файла из сети? При желании можно и Ваш код 405 исправить.

Comment: @woesss Вы абсолютно правы, примеров полно, перепробовал. И главное что похожий код стоит на другом проекте - в этом же случае, как говориться - где-то ";" забыл поставить. Искал причину почему именно 405 - устал ковыряться, решил пойти по протоптанной дорожке - вот и выбрал Picasso.

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei Ваш ответ хоть и не имеет конкретного решения, и тем не менее в нем есть именно та мысль которая стала основой для решения моей проблемы - работа с очередями и потоками. Испытав все что рекоменовали - остановил выбор на RXJava/Android. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Решение с использованием `RXJava 2.1.6` и `Picasso 2.5.2`.

*Вкратце:*
Использовал `Picasso` для загрузки файла в локальное хранилище.
Для соблюдения очередности процессов обернул это все в `RXJava2`.
По окончании загрузки файла передал его на отправку через intent.
Далее выбор приложения *(из списка)* через которое  Вам угодно отправить это фото.

Ссылка на github: **[ImageResender](https://github.com/vmarch/ImageResender.git)**

*Подробно сам код:*

**Manifest:** (обратите внимание на Provider и Permissions)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.devtolife.imageresender">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Layout:** (просто кнопка для запуска получения и передачи картинки).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="START" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Provider:** (`provider_paths.xml` лежит по пути `res/xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

**Gradle:** (подключите библиотеки).

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'
```

**Activity:**
Замечания: 1) `14222` - это эфемерное число взятое с потолка.
2) В `photoURL` - Ссылка на картинку взята с интернета произвольно без цели что либо рекламировать или кого либо обидеть.

```
package com.devtolife.imageresender;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter;
import io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe;
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;

import static android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER = 14222; // 14222 it is the fictional number.

    private static final String TAG = "log";
    private Button btnStart;
    private Context context;
    private String imgName;
    private String photoURL = "http://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/color_effects/1-2-color-effects-free-download-png-thumb.png"; // just for example.

    Uri photoUriForGalleryIndexation;
    Uri photoUri;

    File storageDir;
    private File imgFile = null;

    public File getImgFile() {
        return imgFile;
    }

    public void setImgFile(File imgFile) {
        this.imgFile = imgFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        btnStart = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getRemoteUrlString();

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    createEmptyFile();
                    shareImage();

                } else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getRemoteUrlString() {

        String nameWithExtension = Uri.parse(photoURL).getLastPathSegment();

        int pos = nameWithExtension.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (pos > 0)
            imgName = nameWithExtension.substring(0, pos);
        else
            imgName = nameWithExtension;
    }

    private void createEmptyFile() {

        storageDir = new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MyImages");
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdirs();
            storageDir = new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MyImages");
        }

        setImgFile(new File(storageDir + "/" + imgName + ".jpg"));

        createPhotoUriForIndexation(getImgFile());
        createPhotoUriForSharing(getImgFile());
    }

    private void createPhotoUriForIndexation(File fileIndex) {

        String contentPathString = "imgFile:" + fileIndex.getAbsolutePath();
        photoUriForGalleryIndexation = Uri.parse(contentPathString);

    }

    private void createPhotoUriForSharing(File fileShare) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19) {
            photoUri = Uri.fromFile(fileShare);
        } else {
            photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileShare);
        }
    }

    private void shareImage() {

        Observable<File> observable = Observable
                .create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<File>() {
                            @Override

                            public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<File> emitt) {

                                Picasso.with(context).load(photoURL)
                                        .into(new Target() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                                                try {

                                                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(getImgFile());
                                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);

                                                    if (bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream)) {
                                                        galleryAddPic();
                                                        emitt.onComplete();
                                                    } else {
                                                        emitt.onNext(getImgFile());
                                                    }
                                                    ostream.close();

                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                );


        Observer<File> observer = new Observer<File>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onSubscribe: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(File value) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onNext: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onError: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: All Done!");
                sendImg();
            }
        };

        observable.subscribe(observer);
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(photoUriForGalleryIndexation);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

    }

    private void sendImg() {

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoUri);
        sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER && grantResults.length == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                createEmptyFile();
                shareImage();

            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SENDER);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Может это сэкономит кому-то пару-тройку часов.